# Source of error on psql data load

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, rails

Upon importing a file derived from rails establishment, `psql` is hitting the error of foreign key constraints:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "documents" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_d4abdc7f58"
Key (typ_document_id)=(7) is not present in table "typ_documents".
```

Yet, querying afterwards

```
SELECT * from typ_documents;
```

getting a result

```
  7 | Test Internal | 2013-07-04 08:36:16.026295 | 2013-07-04 08:36:16.026295
```

The only assumption that I can follow is that, when the table `documents` is being loaded, the order of loading is such that `typ_documents` is happening after and the error is arising.  Yet, this error is not occurring consistently and the data dump is in alphabetical order of table names.  Thus, this is a weak assumption.

Removing the foreign key constraint from rails would overcome the problem, but that is a weak reaction.

**Update**
Data from the pg_dump file  (redacted to omit the long full text)

```
COPY documents (id, titolo, abstract, full_text, typ_document_id, idioma_id, competitor_id, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;
[...]
5   Conservazione Finocchio con lavaggio    La prova è stata [...redacted...] 3 ppm\r\n15\t15\r\n0,75\r\n30 sec\t60 sec\t90 sec 7   1   \N  2013-07-08 10:49:53.393598  2013-07-11 16:07:31.540986



COPY typ_documents (id, nome, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;
[...]
7   Test Internal   2013-07-04 08:36:16.026295  2013-07-04 08:36:16.026295
```

How can this issue be debugged/overcome?

Comment: If the dump is ordered alphabetically, then the error is expected.  By consistently, do you mean you always have the same data but the behaviour is different?

Comment: Other tables are imported while using data from subsequently listed tables.  Thus the error appears inconsistent to me.

Comment: Is there only data in the dump or the tables thenselves, too?  Could you show the relevant pieces belonging to either of those two tables?

Comment: the tables are in there as well.  update question.

Comment: What do you mean with "*but that is a weak reaction*"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if a foreign key was established and in use, removing the call is a form of capitulation...

Comment: @Jerome: you can just remove it for the load and then re-create it afterwards. Or declare the constraint as deferrable and import everything in a single transaction (which you should do anyway)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I was going to fall back on a separate load.  However, the suggestion to defer is new and interesting to me.  Upon consulting the documentation `SET CONSTRAINTS` is the call but how does one relate this to the psql call?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is (as a_horse.. says) that your foreign key is not [deferrable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html). Maybe creating your foreign key according the to code below solves your issue.

```
    ALTER TABLE documents
      ADD FOREIGN KEY (typ_document_id)
      REFERENCES typ_documents(id)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
      DEFERRABLE
      INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```